# Did you read The Guardian's editorials today?

Tags: discussion

Wherein Stack Exchange is mentioned, favourably

> Computer programming, for example, would be almost impossible without
>   the resources supplied by Google and Stack Exchange.

[For more see today's Guardian online](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/aug/07/guardian-view-wikipedia-evolving-truth).

Yeah, I know this is a pseudo-question at best but precedent smiles on it.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for letting us know. :)